# SQL FullText Search in cascaded

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

I'm using SQL Server 2012. I have indexed the RFC and IMSS column in the Persons table as full text search index. The table is:

PersonId    RFC                              IMSS 
---------       ------------                       --------------
1                COGS070990IB3           1247587150
2                COGS070990IB3           4781105741
3                FDRH071580AV2           1200467851
4                QWEZ071245JE1           0913218712

I need to search cascaded RFC and then IMSS using the value of string 'COGS070990IB3 1247587150' and the result should be:

PersonId    RFC                              IMSS 
---------       ------------                       --------------
1                COGS070990IB3           1247587150

Is that possible?

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you use full text search for this?  A regular index should be just fine.

Comment: I know, but for academic reasons I would like to know if it is possible and how.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like ;

```
SELECT PersonId, RFC, IMSS FROM dbo.Persons 
WHERE CONTAINS((RFC), 'COGS070990IB3')
AND CONTAINS((IMSS), '1247587150');
```

Source: [FullText search with CONTAINS on multiple columns and predicate - AND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475663/fulltext-search-with-contains-on-multiple-columns-and-predicate-and)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need a query that not separate the string. Something like: SELECT PersonId, RFC, IMSS FROM dbo.Persons 
WHERE CONTAINS((RFC, IMSS), 'COGS070990IB3 1247587150');

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons AS per WHERE FREETEXT(per.*, 'COGS070990IB3 1247587150')
```